# Firefox opens MP4 file in a new tab instead of an HTML video player

Tags: html, firefox, video, mp4, video-player

I have made an MP4 video player according to this tutorial: http://www.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/.

It works well in Chrome and Internet Explorer, but Firefox is opening each link as an MP4 file in a new tab. It plays the first video in the playlist just fine, but when any link in the playlist is clicked, Firefox opens a new tab instead of sending it to the player.

Firefox says:

> TypeError: video[0].play is not a function.

I've just changed the audio variable name to video:

```
function init() {
    current = 0;
    video = $('#video');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    video.volume = .10;
    video[0].play();
    playlist.find('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, video[0]);
    });
    video[0].addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
        current++;
        if (current == len) {
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        } else {
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];
        }
        run($(link), video[0]);
    });
}
```

I have found old topics about this, saying that Firefox just can't play MP4 in an HTML video player, but I wonder if that's still the case.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that your Firefox can't play MP4/H.264. You can check here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html

Recent versions of FF (26+) do support H.264, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Firefox can play mp4 and it plays the first one in the playlist, but when I click on any other links in playlist, it opens a new tab with that mp4 file instead of playing it in the player. Sorry for misunderstandment, I will update the question.

Comment: I see that you are using preventDefault() but you could also try a different element than a link that you attach a click handler to.

Comment: OK, I've just tried using div instead of a tag with my own data-link attribute instead of href. Still no use. Chrome and IE change videos in the player fine, but Firefox isn't responding to clicking, nothing happens.